# apt-get not working correctly because of python3 on lunar

Tags: apt, updates, python

To summarise: apt-get crashes if it detects an error (eg. can't find a repo that is in the sources list).

The problem is caused because the python `sqlite3` shared object has an undefined symbol (`sqlite3_deserialize`). This can be reproduced from `python3 -c 'import sqlite3'`.

Unfortunately, as aptitude is dependent on python3, any failure may cause the python `CommandNotFound` functionality to try to `import sqlite3` and crash (relevant log below).

At the time of writing, it appears that the only available python package is 3.11.2-1 so I can't upgrade/downgrade.

The offending shared object is `/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

apt-file suggests that this file is part of the `libpython3.11-stdlib` package.

I've seen nothing conclusive online about this so maybe I've done something wrong but I can't imagine what. Could anyone running lunar verify this?

Thanks

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 9, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: That symbol should be pulled in from the underlying libsqlite3.so library I think - does `ldd /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` show anything broken?

Comment: Hi steeldriver, thanks for the fast response. It doesn't look broken to me...ldd /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe3f7f7000)
 libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fc8906c5000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc890400000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc890317000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc890839000)

Comment: It looks like you have an incompatible **local** libsqlite3.so (possibly from 3rd party software that you have installed from source) - it should be linking to the system library `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0`

Comment: Amazing! you fixed it! I renamed the offending shared object and it picked up the correct one. Thanks very much.

Comment: For me it was the /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 from filezilla nightly (moved into the local libs). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the issue was operator error. Thanks to steeldriver for pointing me to the cause. Here is an explanation for anyone else who runs into this:

As steeldriver pointed out, python3 was not finding the correct shared object, but was loading one from another installation that I'd inadvertently added at some point.

In this case the error message points to the missing symbol: `sqlite3_deserialize` (a function) that is needed by the shared object `/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

The fault does not lie with this shared object, but the fact that none of the shared objects it loads contains the symbol.

using the `nm` command we can see all the symbols present in the library as well as symbols that it needs. The ones needed are marked as `U`.

`nm -gD /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | less`
If we search for deserialize we can see `U sqlite3_deserialize` indicating that it needs this symbol.

Using `ldd` we can command the linux loader to actually load the library, and all its dependent libraries and find which ones are actually loading:
`ldd /usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

As steeldriver points out, it was loading `/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0` which is not the correct version. Running `nm` on the incorrect file shows that the required symbol is not present in this file, which is the cause of the issue.

The correct sqlite3 package in lunar is `libsqlite3-0` (which is not necessarily obvious). If not sure, we can try to find the correct package from `apt-cache search libsqlite3` or something similar and sift through the results.

We can see what files are installed by this package by first installing it, then running `dpkg -L libsqlite3-0`. In the returned list if files we see `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0` which is the one that should be loaded.

So how do we ensure that the linux loader picks the correct shared object version? Ideally we should only have one version of sqlite3 so the best solution is to remove the non-standard one. Another potential solution is to point the loader to the correct path using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Something like this may work `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (add to `~/.bashrc` for persistence). Note that putting it at the front will cause that directory to be searched first. If the problem still persists then just run `ldd` again to verify what's being loaded.